# How to change the url according to the cookie state

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress plugin
I set cookie when a user clicks on one of the following buttons

`Fluid`    `Women`    `Men`

Here is the [image: picture]

I want to use the cookie state across all pages of the website once its is set as query parameters.

I have appended the dynamic cookie as query parameters (as I need) with the `url` and then trying to reload it like this

`

```
      $to_laod = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'].'?filter_gender='.$_COOKIE['gender'].'&query_type_gender=or'; //abc.com/prod-category/fashion/?filter_gender=men&query_type_gender=or

        header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
            header("Location:". $to_laod);
```

`If I have this type of link`abc.com/prod-category/fashion/?filter_gender=men&query_type_gender=or`statically, it works fine, but when I make it dynamic it gives me`err_too_many_redirects`
how to solve this problem?

I have tried with header("Location:link") but I don't know if I'm on the right path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be lost in loop of redirection when the current filter_gender on the URL is matching gender with the value in cookie. So a logic check like this should help you avoid too many redirects error.

```
if($_COOKIE['gender'] !== $_GET['gender']) {
    $to_laod = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'].'?filter_gender='.$_COOKIE['gender'].'&query_type_gender=or'; //abc.com/prod-category/fashion/?filter_gender=men&query_type_gender=or

    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location:". $to_laod);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @vincent_oupsouch but now I have another problem

Comment: It redirects correctly but the widget of the `filter by gender` does not work properly now,